# Printing prompt from input statement?

Tags: python

I have an issue using dcoder. My input is:
20
50 8
30 10

Its outputting not 80 alone but the prompts from the input statements also. How do I get it to just print 80?

```
maxw =  int(input("bag weight: "))
itemOne = input("item value & weight:") #item 1 
itemTwo = input("item value & weight:") #item 2
lone, ltwo = itemOne[0:3], itemTwo[0:3]  #rid of " "
iione, iitwo = int(lone), int(ltwo) #change to int

def total_value(x, y):
    tval = x + y             #add together 50 and 80
    return tval

result = total_value(iione, iitwo)
print(result)
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Jh4.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCAcC.png)
```

Comment: Can you post exactly what the output looks like? Also, your lines for `itemOne` and `itemTwo` are expecting what sort of input? "Item value and weight" sound like two different entries and should probably be stored in separate variables.

Comment: You "_rid of " "_" by calling method `str.strip()`, but since you convert the results to a number, even that is not needed: just do `iione=int(itemOne)`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the displayed input statements prompts? If your script prints anything after they execute, then they will just scroll upwards until they disapread off the top of the screen/window.

Comment: The coding prompt is a treasure hunt. Your bag can hold 20 pounds. Thats the First line of input. The second line of input is: 50 8.  The third line of input is: 30 10. The value and weight of each item seperated by a space.  My output is: bag weight: value & weight: value & weight: 80

Comment: When I enter the same code interactively my result is just the integer 80.

Comment: you can add intermediate print statements to verify whether the inputs are assigned correctly to the variables iione & iitwo